# Set some space inside editText

Tags: android, android-edittext

Can I set some space inside 'EditText' in the beginning and at the end? If possible, then how? Actually, I have done some customization on my 'EditText' view and now it shows like this, as shown in the below image:

[image: Emulator screen shot]

In my case, as you see, in my "description" field, the word "Description" starts from the very beginning, which doesnt look attractive, I want to keep some space in the beginning and at the end of the EditText's text. And also i want to set this, at the run time as this editText views are set on the runtime after a selection from the spinner. Can i achieve this?

Comment: If the background is a [9patch](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/draw9patch.html), you can do this by specifying the content area, and it will apply even if you are creating the **EditText** during runtime. Anyhow, you can still use the method proposed by @RobinHood.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `padding left` like

`editText.setPadding (int left, int top, int right, int bottom);`

Answer (score 2):

try this code

```
 android:paddingLeft="5dp"
```

Comment: Okay... But my views are generated on run-time. I need to set this padding programaticaly in java code. Can you write me this code...??

Comment: Thanks for your replying me. Even your code would be helpful to me next time when i will need to do this in xml.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code.....

```
        android:includeFontPadding="true"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your java code

```
 editText.setPadding( 5, 0,0,0);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this through XML as well in coding.
If you want to do in XML, You have to do the padding to required Edit text.

```
<EditText
android:id="@+id/bt_description"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:paddingLeft="10dp" />
```

If not you can do this through code as above said.

```
email.setPadding(int left,int top,int right,int bottom);
```